# Numerical Differentiation of a Numerical Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, function-construction, numerical-value

I am trying to evaluate the following expression numerically 
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{-2t^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\xi/\sqrt{2}}{\xi^{3/2}}e^{(-\xi^2/2-2\xi t))}$$

My code is as follows

```
f[t_]:=Exp[-2*t^2]*NIntegrate[Erf[\[Xi]/Sqrt[2]]/\[Xi]^(3/2)*Exp[-(\[Xi]^2/2)-2*\[Xi]*t],{\[Xi],0,Infinity}]
Der[t_] := f''[t]
```

But when I evaluate, say by entering

```
Der[5]
```

I am getting an error that the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region. Now I know that this is a common error, and other threads have revealed that this is happening because Mathematica is not recognizing something in my expression (likely $\xi$) as a numerical variable. However, I am not sure how I would go about fixing this. I have tried putting in ?NumericQ beside all instances of $\xi$ but that didn't seem to work.

How would I go about numerically evaluating this expression (and ideally, plotting it as a function of t) without the NIntegrate::inumr error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not simplify the integrand by dividing out $\xi$ and bringing out constants?  And you need a $d \xi$ within the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

f[t_?NumericQ] := 
 Exp[-2*t^2]*
  NIntegrate[
   Erf[ξ/Sqrt[2]]/ξ^(3/2)*
    Exp[-(ξ^2/2) - 2*ξ*t], {ξ, 0, Infinity}]
```

Use [`ND`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html)

```
Der[t_?NumericQ] := ND[f[x], {x, 2}, t]

Der[5]

(*  3.41091*10^-20  *)
```

Comment: @PratikSamant - I just copied and pasted and evaluated without any problems. You apparently have problems with prior definitions. Either clear all variables or start with a fresh kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: my formula contains a sign error (-t instaed of +t). But the derivation is still valid. Only the final numeric value must be taken at t = -5.

The integral can be written as

```
f[t_] := 
 NIntegrate[\[Xi]^(-3/2 )
    Erf[\[Xi]/Sqrt[2]] Exp[-(1/2) (\[Xi] - 2 t)^2], {\[Xi], 
   0, \[Infinity]}]
```

Let us form the second derivative with respect to `t` under the integral:

```
D[Exp[-1/2 (\[Xi] - 2 t)^2], {t, 2}]

(* Out[22]= -4 E^(-(1/2) (-2 t + \[Xi])^2) + 
 4 E^(-(1/2) (-2 t + \[Xi])^2) (-2 t + \[Xi])^2 *)
```

and call `f''[t] = f2[t]` which is

```
f2[t_] := 
 NIntegrate[\[Xi]^(-3/2 )
    Erf[\[Xi]/Sqrt[2]] 4 E^(-(1/
     2) (-2 t + \[Xi])^2) (-1 + (-2 t + \[Xi])^2), {\[Xi], 
   0, \[Infinity]}]
```

The value requested is then

```
f2[5]

(* Out[24]= 0.0129202 *)
```

This is very different from Bob Hanlon's result which is, in fact

```
f2[-5]

(* Out[30]= 3.43309*10^-20 *)
```